# stripe not forwarding events to my local end point

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I have followed the stripes webhooks cli to test on a local enviroment. The first two steps checked out but when it comes to trigering events, it wount trigger my local end point even tho the CMD says trigger succeeded. My webhook is listening on port 4242

```
// Match the raw body to content type application/json
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), (request, response) => {
  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      request.body,
      request.headers['stripe-signature'],
      process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(`âš ï¸  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
    console.log(
      `âš ï¸  Check the env file and enter the correct webhook secret.`
    );
    return response.sendStatus(400);
  }

  // Extract the object from the event.
  const dataObject = event.data.object;

  //store the stripe customer
  const customerId = dataObject.customer

  // Handle the event
  // Review important events for Billing webhooks
  // https://stripe.com/docs/billing/webhooks
  // Remove comment to see the various objects sent for this sample
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'invoice.paid':

      console.log("invoice paid")

      //set users subscription to active
      Billing.find({ stripeCustomerId: customerId })
        .then(data => {

          data[0].Subscription = "active"
          data[0].save()
        })



      // Used to provision services after the trial has ended.
      // The status of the invoice will show up as paid. Store the status in your
      // database to reference when a user accesses your service to avoid hitting rate limits.
      break;
    case 'invoice.payment_failed':

      //check to see if the subscription is inactive
      Billing.find({ stripeCustomerId: customerId })
        .then(data => {

          data[0].Subscription = "past_due"
          data[0].save()
        })

      console.log("invoice failed")
      break;

    case 'customer.subscription.deleted':

      //check to see if the subscription is inactive
      Billing.find({ stripeCustomerId: customerId })
        .then(data => {

          data[0].Subscription = "inactive"
          data[0].save()
        })

      console.log("subscription delted")
      break;
    default:
    // Unexpected event type
  }
  response.sendStatus(200);
});
```

I need to figure out if my code is the problem as to why it is not forwarding events to my localhost:5000/webhook

Comment: Have you run event forwarding command via Stripe CLI with the [step](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#local-listener) here? Events will only be forwarded to local endpoint when the command is run.

Comment: @yuting yes the event forwading checks out but whenever i want to trigeer an event its not forwarding to my local endpoint. not sure why

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out what the problem was. when running stripe cli, u need to have two terminals open. the first temrinal you have to run `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:4242/webhook` you need to live this terminal open so stripe cli will be able to forward events to your local webhooks. you will now open a second terminal where you will be running your events.